# Pass multiple IDs, get first record only in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

How can I get only the first record using multiple IDs in Laravel? In the following code, `$ids` has three elements. I want to fetch the first record from table using these three IDs.

```
$ids = [16, 18, 20];

$listing = Listing::whereIn('id', $ids)->first();
```

Comment: Use `Listing::where('id', $ids[0])->get();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use either limit or oldest function of laravel see below query

```
  $listing = Listing::whereIn('id', $ids)->limit(1)->get(); //using limit
    OR
  $listing = Listing::whereIn('id', $ids)->oldest('id')->first(); //using oldest()
```

Comment: With `latest()` OP will get the last object, not first.

Comment: you can use oldest instead of latest, i have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the first object with smallest id, you can do:

```
$listing = Listing::whereIn('id', $ids)->oldest('id')->first();
```

But better to do this:

```
$listing = Listing::find(min($ids));
```

If you want to get an object with the first ID in the array, do this:

```
$listing = Listing::find($ids[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do this would be to sort the id column like so:

```
$listing = Listing::whereIn('id', $ids)->orderBy('id')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
$ids=[16,18,20];

foreach($ids as $id){
  $listing[] = Listing::where('id', $id)->first();
}
```

Hope this work for you!